# App notifications block setting not set after phone restart

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, settings, notifications, reboot, sony-xperia-z1

I updated my **`Sony Xperia Z1`**'s Android to **`Lollipop`** (official update from Sony) a few days ago, and just noticed that the applications having their notifications **`blocked`** reset back when my phone is restarted. The **`Priority`** and **`Sensitive`** options are saved but the **`Block`** option appears to be not. For your information, the app I'm blocking is **`Psiphon`** – but testing this with other apps revealed it affects almost all of them, with a few exceptions only.

What could be the problem? Possible bug of Android?

Thanks

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. Its hard to say if the way its behaving (since it happens to **all** apps) is either a bug or that's how it was designed to work. If you could perhaps read more about the update from Sony and learn more about the Notifications Manager. I am on 5.1.1 with CyanogenMod, and my notifications blocking etc are persistent.

Comment: I doubt Sony would do such a thing. Thanks any way, appreciate it.

Comment: @Rexford I just found out that some apps keep the blocked option. It seems that just `**Psiphon`** and some other apps doesn't.

Comment: This only started happening after the recent update so I would suggest this is a bug.